# Lotus Notes Integration to Google Team-drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a requirement to create a Lotus Notes java agent that needs to upload a folder/files from local directory to Google Team Drive for scheduled backup. I did some research about the Google API's (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) for java but I'm having some difficulties trying to understand all those java code as I only have a basic knowledge in java. If I understand it correctly, the api requires a maven repository and need to define all the dependencies which are not supported in Lotus Notes (not sure about this and am I reading the correct documentation).

May be someone can tell me if this is possible and point me out where to start. You might have some sample code that I can use as a reference. Any help and suggestion is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to just upload the DB files to Drive? Or do you want to upload the Lotus Notes profiles?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to create a daily, weekly, monthly backup copy of the nsf file and  reports. It's an existing process, the only thing that needs to be changed is to upload the files/folders into team drive programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the Drive Java Quickstart [1], where you will find the prerequisites and links of how to install Gradle (which is pretty similar to Maven) and the steps to build the JAVA application to make the requests to the Drive API.

Apparently, you wouldn’t have a problem to install gradle in lotus notes, either using this plugin [2] or installing eclipse [3], and then installing gradle inside eclipse.

Following the quickstart, the Java Drive documentation [4] and this google guide to upload files [5], I created and tested this code successfully:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DriveQuickstart {
    //General Variables
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);

        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");


    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build the news authorized API client services.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("Filename");
        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(“Complete-File-Path”);
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
        File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

    }
}
```

Just for your information, there’s a tool you can use to migrate all your information from Lotus Notes to G suite [6].

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

[2] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYJJF_1.0.0/ApplicationSecurityonCloud/src_irx_gen_gradle.html

[3] https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-eclipse/

[4] https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/

[5] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

[6] https://support.google.com/a/answer/161642?hl=en

Comment: I have successfully tested the api with gradle. What I'm trying right now is to migrate the api in java agent. I have put all the necessary jar files in "<notesdir>\jvm\lib\ext" folder and updated the java policy to allow permissions to external resources. So far, my code compiled successfully but I'm having a "access denied" runtime error when accessing the windows download and upload directory. I spent the whole day trying to fix this error with no luck. You experts might have some knowledge on this error.

Comment: Probably a problem with permission access from lotus notes? Don't know much about lotus notes, i suggest you make a new question with the complete message error.

Comment: Installing gradle in Lotus notes is interesting as I never thought it was possible. I will read all those links and try. Thanks for the advised. Really appreciate it. Keep it coming. :)

Comment: There's no error if I access the folder with pure lotus notes java (without using external jar file). The error occur when the external class/method access the wibdows folder or file. Yes, posted another questions about the error a while ago and I hope someone can help.